# Running android application on all screen sizes

Tags: android

My android application is running good on emulators form 1.5v to 2.2v

when I installed .apk file on SAMSUNG GALAXY-3 v2.1 screen sizes are not matching.But
the same  .apk file supporting the UI on SAMSUNG v1.5

I want to run my application on any screen sizes.

Comment: What do you mean the screen sizes don't match? You can run your app on ay android device.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand your frustration, i had the same problem recently.

You need to add the following lines to your AndroidManifest.xml file:
supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"

This makes ur app work on devices with any screen size.
(FYI : supports-screens is a tag in the file, i have written it without tags because it cant be displayed here with tags)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create different layout folder for Supporting Multiple Screens

*layout-small

layout-normal

layout-large*
it better to refer http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html